# How to calculate min entropy of the output of PRNG?

Tags: entropy

As min entropy of a random variable provides the maximum probability of getting the desired realization of the random variable, which is the most conservative way of measuring the uncertainty of outcomes. Min entropy analysis is required to bound the characteristics of the attacker's perceived observation from the output of the PRNG.

Comment: Are you trying to measure it by observing output or by analyzing the PRNG?

Comment: I am trying to measure by observing output of the PRNG. @bmm6o

Comment: I don't see how this can work.  You can't even distinguish a good PRNG from a true random source, so an entropy estimate has to grow without bound as more output is seen.

Comment: If my seed key is k and output length of the PRNG is bounded by 2^k-1,in that case,is it possible to estimate min entropy? @bmm6o

Comment: You don't even need a calculation: It's 0.

Comment: See this answer to a related question: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/10408/4241

Comment: @CodesInChaos To my annoyance and everyone's on going confusion, no one has sufficiently either equated nor differentiated between cryptographic entropy, information entropy and Kolmogorov complexity. For instance your above comment regarding H(PRNG) = 0 is diametrically opposite to bmm60's linked accepted answer, and I believe Shannon's notion of entropy...

Comment: @PaulUszak Since this is "**cryptography** StackExhchange", it's safe to assume that when we talk about entropy, we are talking about *cryptographic entropy*. I hope that helps lifting your (quote) *"on going confusion"*.

Comment: @e-sushi I get your sentiment but no, not really :-(.  Simply inventing a 'special' type of entropy that's tangential to that in all other disciplines doesn't help.    _"No body knows what entropy really is"_ as proven by all the questions on this forum.  I'll just remain confused along with the rest...